# Vuejs v-movable with @click is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

Im trying to implement a moveable text that can also be click and call the method. However when i try to put @click its not calling the function. Can anyone help me? Thank you..

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <a @click="next()">
        <movable class="testmove" posTop="222" posLeft="222" shiftKey="true"
          ><span>Shift Key Behavior</span></movable
        >
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import movable from "v-movable";
export default {
  name: "app",
  movable,
  methmethods: {
    next() {
      alert("Hello");
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}
.movable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.testmove {
  /* display:block;
    position: absolute; */
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;

  background: #333;
  color: white;
}
.modaltitle {
  background: blue;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Here is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-darkness-0zm03?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: do you want click event? or mouse press down event (start dragging)?

Comment: yes i want to click event

Comment: @start is not what you want?

Comment: there is start event for v-movable `@start: fires immediately after the pointerdown event on the element`

Comment: no not @start just click event which i can drag the text then at the same time i can also click it

Comment: can you give me a sample of @start in v-movable? Really appreciate your help

Comment: <movable @start="next()" ...>

Comment: i already put the <movable @start="next()" ...> but it showing me error. it says "Property or method next is not defined but i have next in my method"

Comment: there is a typo in your code `methmethods` which should be corrected to `methods`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is a typo in your code `methmethods` which should be corrected to `methods`
- You can use start event for the `v-movable`.

```
@start: fires immediately after the pointerdown event on the element
```

Comment: can i ask again  aside from @start is there any other event handler in v-moveble cause i want to drag first before the methods run. Sorryyy

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-movable#events-prefer-over-attrib-handlers-above